# Extract certain part of filename in Bash

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have many files in a folder:

```
yyyymmdd_hhmmss.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_suffix1.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_suffix1_suffix2.mp4
```

The following filename formats are also possible (rarely):

```
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$$$.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$$$_suffix1.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$$$_suffix1_suffix2.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$$.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$$_suffix1.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$$_suffix1_suffix2.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$_suffix1.mp4
yyyymmdd_hhmmss_$_suffix1_suffix2.mp4
```

where $ is a number 0-9

I am trying to catch "yyyymmdd_hhmmss" and use it as an argument.
This is what I do when only one suffix presented:

```
for file in "$@"; do 
  file_nosuffix="${file%*_suffix1.mp4}.mp4"
  echo "$file and $file_nosuffix"
done
```

But I get lost when all sorts of the filename formats mentioned above are presented.
Ideally I would like to stick to the current pattern:

```
for file in "$@"; do 
   #catch "yyyymmdd_hhmmss"
   #do something on files yyyymmdd_hhmmss.mp4
   #do something else on files yyyymmdd_hhmmss_suffix1.mp4
   #etc.
done
```

Is that possible?

Comment: why don't you just save the first 15 characters into a variable?

Comment: As an aside, `for file` iterates over `"$@"` by default.

Comment: Also, as an aside, it's helpful to provide test data that actually matches your stated format, rather than something that's descriptive to humans but can't be used for actual testing. `yyyymmdd_hhmmss` doesn't match something that expects all those characters to be digits, for example, which is *presumably* your actual format.

Comment: As a reference to get a substring: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/bash-string-manipulation/

Comment: Actually, I'd suggest [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) (part of the Wooledge wiki, maintained by the denizens of the irc.freenode.org #bash channel) for a discussion of string manipulation in bash over some random website. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe is also reputable (and actively maintained).

Comment: @Kathara, there's a lot of bad information about bash on highly-rated sites on Google (TLDP is perhaps the worst offender in terms of misinformation:pagerank ratio). The point was thus very deliberate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy With the information you added after, yes. But just stating that it would be better without giving a reason, for someone who's a novice this is also something I would not recommend... Sorry for the harsh comment and thanks for the information.

Answer (score 4):

Bash has built-in regex support, if you want to confirm the format:

```
regex='^[[:digit:]]{8}_[[:digit:]]{6}' # POSIX ERE; can't use PCRE extensions here

for file; do
  if [[ $file =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "${BASH_REMATCH[0]} is the substring for $file" >&2
  else
    echo "$file does match the required format" >&2
  fi
done
```

One can also trivially take a prefix;

```
for file; do
  prefix=${file:0:15}
  echo "Prefix for $file is $prefix"
done
```

...or, to delete the last two underscores and everything after them:

```
prefix=${file%_*_*}
```

---

See:

- [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) ("How can I do string manipulations in bash?")
- [Parameter Expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I think I am going to go ahead and take a prefix. However I wonder if there is a way to write code that will work for anyname_suffix1_suffix2.mp4

Comment: What logic do you actually want? Just kill `_*_*` from the end? `prefix=${file%_*_*}`, then.

Comment: prefix=${file%_*_*} is brilliant, that is exactly what I want!! Thank you @Charles Duffy

Comment: Amended, then. (You can mark your question answered via the checkbox next to the answer).